# Disable items in ng-repeat list on click of one other item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my plnkr with my progress so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/iEHMUMlASZaqdMQUeF7J?p=preview

I'm having problems implementing the following functionality however.

When an item on the list is clicked, I need to disable the remaining items on the list. ie, another request should not take place, and these remaining items' colour should change to indicate the disabled state.

Once the request has taken place, then the entire list should go back to the original state.

Edit: I've made some progress. Although a bit messy it's getting me a bit closer. My problem is the following line:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('item-selected').children().unbind('click').removeClass('pending');
```

This prevents the click event running more than once at a time. However it's stopping the click event from running all together once its run for the first time. I would like to be able to re-run the process once it is complete an unlimited amount of times.

Directive:

```
app.directive('listItem', function (ListService, $timeout, $location) {
      return {
        restrict: 'ACE',
        controller : 'ItemController',
        template: '<p>{{item}} {{foo}}</p>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          $(element).bind('click', function (e) {
              $(this).parent().addClass('item-selected').children().unbind('click').removeClass('pending');
              $(this).addClass('pending');
              var elem = $(this);
              $timeout(function () {
                ListService
                  .selectItem(scope.item)
                  .then( function () {
                      console.log('success');
                      elem.removeClass('pending').addClass('success');
                      //$location.path('foo.html')
                      scope.foo = 'not bar';
                  }, function () {
                      console.log('error');
                      elem.removeClass('pending').addClass('error');
                      elem.parent().removeClass('item-selected');
                  });
                ;
              }, 2000);
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

The entire app code including directive:

```
var app = angular.module('listtestApp', []);
    app.service('ListService', function ($http) {
      var data = [
        'alpha',
        'bravo',
        'charlie',
        'delta',
        'foxtrot'
      ];
      return {
        getData : function () {
          return data;
        },
        selectItem : function () {
          return $http({ method: 'GET', url : '/data/list.json'});
        }
      }
    });


    app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, ListService) {
      $scope.list = ListService.getData();
      $scope.foo = 'Bar';
    });


    app.controller('ItemController', function ($scope, ListService) {

    });


    app.directive('listItem', function (ListService, $timeout, $location) {
      return {
        restrict: 'ACE',
        controller : 'ItemController',
        template: '<p>{{item}} {{foo}}</p>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          $(element).bind('click', function (e) {
              $(this).parent().addClass('item-selected').children().unbind('click').removeClass('pending');
              $(this).addClass('pending');
              var elem = $(this);
              $timeout(function () {
                ListService
                  .selectItem(scope.item)
                  .then( function () {
                      console.log('success');
                      elem.removeClass('pending').addClass('success');
                      //$location.path('foo.html')
                      scope.foo = 'not bar';
                  }, function () {
                      console.log('error');
                      elem.removeClass('pending').addClass('error');
                  });
                ;
              }, 2000);
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

html markup below:

```
 <body ng-app="listtestApp">
   <div ng-controller="ListController">
     <div ng-repeat="item in list" list-item>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: please post the relevant parts of your code here so they can be seen without having to go to another site.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I pasted the angular code I'm using into my post above. thanks for your help.

Comment: post your ng-repeat html code - you might be able to use a filter to achieve what you want to do easily

Comment: I've added it. Thanks ewizard. A filter would be great. But note, I'm not looking to hide any of the items in the list. I would just like to apply a disabled class for the non-clicked items and an active class to the clicked item, and remove all of this when the request is finished. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You have several solutions at your disposal :

- [Check that any element has the `pending` or `success` or `error` class](http://plnkr.co/edit/ypNQoJkadv0959yMtnzk?p=preview)
- [use your function scope to store it in a variable](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ES0wNpm1mkwoB4ietlm?p=preview)

EDIT : if you want to re-enable selection after the request has been posted, you could use something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/toEeSxL1BUYDobcv2fps?p=preview) (variant of version #1)

Comment: Thanks for your help Ven. How would I add a disabled state (class of .disabled) to  to either of these methods? 

Also I need to be able to repeat the request once it is complete, which isn't possible with your second example.

Note. I can't get the first one to work. Thanks again.

Comment: The first one has a hanging "debugger", that's why. To implement .disabled, you should use the scope (like `$scope.selectedItem`, with `ng-class={"disabled":disabledItem!=currentItem}"`)

Comment: Okay I'll give that a go, but still unsure as to how I would be able to get function to run again after it is complete? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean ?

Comment: My apologies. I need to be able to click a different item or even the same item and make the call once more, after it has already run for a first time. Thanks.

Comment: Oooh, you mean you shouldn't be able to click while you're processing a request ?

Comment: That's correct. Not being able to click whilst processing a request. But then being able to click again on any item once the process is complete to start a new process.